# How do I use the value of a column in a csv to determine value of another column in the same csv using bash?

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, grep

I have a large csv containing database information that I would like to update.

**I would like to use the values in the email column (column 1) to determine the value of the segment column (column 4).**

For example, if the email contains 'nhs.net' then the segment column should read 'Health - NHS'.

Currently the segment column reads 'Unknown Specialism' and I'm not sure how to overwrite this value using bash based on if the value in another column is true.

**Example**

zoe.russell@nhs.net, zoe, russell, **Unknown Specialism**

will become:

zoe.russell@nhs.net, zoe, russell, **Health - NHS**

I have this so far...(my first bash script, and first q on here)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'enter the email domain you are searching for in the email field'
read email 
echo 'please enter the file you wish to search'
read file
echo 'ok looking for' $email 'in' $file
echo ...
# cat $file | grep -E -i $email

x=$(cat $file | grep -E -i $email | wc -l)
echo 'ok' $x 'email address were found in' $file
echo 'here is a sample of the first 10 lines in the segment column' 
cat us.tmp | cut -d ',' -f10 | head -10 

echo 'please enter the segment name you want to replace these with'
read new
echo value will be replaced with $new
```

Comment: *segment column (column 3)* - actually, it's on 4th column

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, you can use below awk -

```
$cat file
zoe.russell@nhs.net, zoe, russell, Unknown Specialism
```

---

```
$awk -F, '{if($1 ~ /nhs.net/) {$4=" Health - NHS"}; print $0}' OFS=, f
zoe.russell@nhs.net, zoe, russell, Health - NHS
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk using another file for the segment column replacements:

```
$ cat repl.txt
nhs.net, Health - NHS
```

The code:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }                            # delimiters are: ,
NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next }                      # read replacements in a hash
split($1,t,"@") && (t[2] in a) {                # get the domain name and use is 
    $NF=a[t[2]]                                 # as reference to a hash
}
1' repl.txt file                                # 1 is the print command
zoe.russell@nhs.net, zoe, russell, Health - NHS
```